# C++ Primer 5th Edition exercise 3.20 Adding Elements to a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I just started learning C++ with C-Prime 5th Edition. And in problem 3.20 "Read a set of integers into a vector. Print the sum of each pair of adjacent elements". I finish the code as below but my terminal does not execute the summary code. I still can not figure it out that is there a problem with my VSCode or my code is wrong somewhere and gets overflowed. When I tested to print something out whenever the push_back work and there is no problem with that, there is no error message, the code just stop after adding elements to the vector I guess.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    int b;
    while(cin >> b)
    {
        a.push_back(b);
    }
    for (decltype(a.size())c = 0; c < (a.size() - 1); ++c)
    {
        auto d = a[c] + a [c+1];
        cout << "sum of " <<a[c]<<" and "<<a[c+1]<<" is: "<<d<<endl;
        d = 0;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    
}
```

input: 1 2 3 4 5
then the code stop.
Thankyou in advance.

Comment: How are you signalling that you don't want to input any more numbers? Note that pressing enter is not sufficient. The program will keep waiting for input.

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon in the debugger. With a debugger you can run the program line by line and see what happens as it happens. When you see the program do something you did not expect, you have usually found a bug.

Comment: @cigien thankyou so much, I set 0 as a break point of while and the code ran perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to stop the program. The program doesn't know how many numbers you want to put in.  Perhaps write a for loop that only iterates 5 times so you get 5 inputs like this:

```cpp
int b;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    cin >> b;
    a.push_back(b);
}
```